# How do I prevent event listeners from crashing?

Tags: android-studio, android-viewpager

When I input a number in the text view, I want the images in that order to appear in the `ViewPager`. And also, when I move the page, I want the `EditText` to display the position value of the page. Entering a value in the editText to get to that page solved it. However, if I touch the page even slightly, an error pops up immediately.

When I saw the `logcat's` error, it tells me that `text,setText(position+1);` and `pager.setCurrentItem(index-1);` are errors. I Think that, there is a conflict between the two event listeners.
What should I do?

```
public class SlideshowFragment extends Fragment {

    ViewPager pager;
    fragment1 frag1;
    fragment2 frag2;
    ...
    fragment29 frag29;
    fragment30 frag30;
    MyPageAdapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slideshow, container, false);

        pager = root.findViewById(R.id.Pager);
        adapter = new MyPageAdapter(getParentFragmentManager());
        final EditText text = root.findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(30);
        text.setText("1");

        frag1 = new fragment1();
        frag2 = new fragment2();
       ...
        frag30 = new fragment30();

        adapter.addItem(frag1);
        ...
        adapter.addItem(frag30);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                int index = 1;
                String str = null;
                if(editable != null){
                    str = editable.toString();
                    if(isInteger(str))
                        index = Integer.parseInt(str);
                    if (index <= 30 && index >= 1)
                        pager.setCurrentItem(index-1);
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a digit number between 1~30 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }


        });

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                text.setText(position+1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
        return root;
    }


    private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        ArrayList<Fragment> images = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        public MyPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addItem(Fragment fragment){
            images.add(fragment);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return images.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.size();
        }

    }

    public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I changed the 'text.setText(position+1)' to 'text.setText(position+1+" ")'. Then it doesn't turn off, but the slide doesn't go over. Why?